# How to handle exception and repeat with Rx

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I am performing an `IO` operation using `Observable.FromAsync`.I want to repeat this forever.What i do not understand is how to handle exceptions , do something with them and then go back in my loop:

What i have tried:

```
IObservable<string> ioObs=Observable.FromAsync<string>([something]);  //at each iteration i do an io operation (reading from a socket);
IObservable<string> loop=Observable.Catch(ioObs).Repeat();
loop.Subscribe(
  onNext:x=> Console.Writeline($"Message:{x}"),
  onCompleted: Console.Writeline("Completed"),
  onError: ex=>Console.Writeline($"Error\tReason:{ex.Message}")
);
```

Now i do not understand why does my observable end  after the first exception.Am i not telling it to continue.

What i want to do:

- perform IO action
- if it throws return some custom value
- repeat the loop

If my observable was an enumerable i would've wanted this kind of behaviour:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<string> EnumerableBehaviour()
{
   while(true)
   {
      try
      {
        string data=await ReadAsync();  //the `FromAsync` delegate
        yield return data;
      }catch(Exception ex)
          yield return "Error";
      {
   }
}
```

How do i continue the execution of `Repeat` even if `OnError` was triggered ?

How should `Observable.Catch` and `Observable.Throw` be combined with `Observable.Repeat` ?

Comment: Can you handle the exception inside the `[something]`?

Comment: I could handle it , but  more out of curiosity , can it be handled outside by using only `Rx` constructs? Can a new `Observable` be constructed after the `Error` ? If so does `Repeat` make sense anymore ? Could i say something like `myobservable.Catch(myobservable)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observable is dead once an exception is thrown. It's the same as with a normal method execution. When an exception is thrown it is handled at the place where the `try`-`catch` block is. It is not possible to "go back" where the exception was generated originally and continue from there. Same as for observables.

The `Observable.Catch()` extension methods can be used to catch such an exception (from the now dead observable) and continue with a new observable instead. The overload [`Observable.Catch(IObservable<TSource>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229103(v=vs.103)) you are using uses a `params` parameter for the `IObservable` objects to use. When the first one fails with an exception, jump to the second one. If that one fails, jump to the third one, and so on. However, you have provided only one observable with `Observable.Catch(ioObs)`, so there is nothing to jump to when the first observable fails.

It might be possible when you use the [other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229717(v=vs.103)) which expects an enumerable of subscriptions to use. When one fails the next one will be used. See the following example:

```
public static int requestCounter = 0;
public static Task<string> SomeSourceMethod() {
    Random r = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    if (r.NextDouble() < 0.5) {
        Console.Write("E ");
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return Task.FromResult($"test {requestCounter++}");
}
    
public static IEnumerable<IObservable<string>> ObservableEnumerable() {
    for (;;) {
        IObservable<string> foo = Observable.FromAsync<string>(SomeSourceMethod);
        IObservable<string> fooRepeated = foo.Repeat();
        yield return fooRepeated;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IObservable<string> endless = ObservableEnumerable().Catch();
    IDisposable subscription = endless
        .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(it => Console.WriteLine(it));

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Terminating the subscription");
    subscription.Dispose();
}
```

This might generate an output like this:

```
E test 1
E E E E test 2
test 3
test 4
test 5
test 6
E E test 7
test 8
E test 9
Terminating the subscription
E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E
```

However it didn't work right as I had to hard kill the process to stop. It kinda(?) works somehow, but I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do it that way (probably not).

Comment: So you are saying that basically when my observable dies , i need to spawn a new one and then attach the subscriber to it.What i don't get is you just use `Catch` without providing a continuation observable (even though your `Observable` is endless). So you `yield`-ing observables but if one fails how does the `Catch` block help you ? Also how are you using `SubscribeOn` since you are getting an `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian `ObservableEnumerable()` is returning an enumerable of `IObservable<string>` instances. The `Catch()` extension method will use this enumerable and start using the first observable from that enumerable. When it fails it uses the next one from the enumerable. So the `subscription` variable will have one active subscription which prints the generated strings, but in reality the underlying source is failing 50% with an exception, which is handled by the `Catch()` call (to jump to the next observable).

Comment: So basically you created a factory of observables and use `Catch` to jump from one to another when the first dies.

Comment: It is dangerous throwing the error inside a method that returns a `Task<T>` by using `Task.FromResult(...)`. The whole method should be wrapped in a `Task.Run(() => ...)` and the exception thrown from in there. It dramatically changes the way the observable operates. If you change your method then you'll find that you won't get the `E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E E ` after the `Terminating the subscription`. The observable would then properly terminate.

Comment: Using `for (;;) { ... yield }` is chewing up a thread too. That's a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

When you have an `IObservable<string> ioObs = Observable.FromAsync<string>(Something);` you have an observable that can either return a value and then complete ({OnNext}{OnCompleted}) or you have one that will throw an exception ({OnError}).

It's very simple to allow the source to repeatedly execute after returning values or errors.

```
IObservable<string> query = ioObs.Retry().Repeat();
```

`.Retry()` says "go again if you get an error". `.Repeat()` says "subscribe again if the observable completes".

Now this is a bit dangerous as you have produced an observable that will execute continuously. You need to find some way to stop it.

Your choices are:

- Dispose of the subscription
- Take a certain number of values (i.e. `.Take(n)`)
- Set a `.Timeout`.
- Or use `TakeUntil`

The last one is good when your original `ioObs` returns a null or empty string on completion.

You can do something like this:

```
IObservable<string> query = ioObs.Retry().Repeat()
        .TakeUntil(x => x == null);
```

Here's a test bit of code that you can try this on:

```
private int __counter = 0;
Task<string> Something()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref __counter) % 7 == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Blam!");
        }
        return $"Hello World {__counter}";
    });
}
```

And then do this:

```
IObservable<string> ioObs = Observable.FromAsync<string>(Something);

IObservable<string> query = ioObs.Retry().Repeat()
        .TakeUntil(x => x.EndsWith("19"));
```

When I subscribe I get:

```
Hello World 1 
Hello World 2 
Hello World 3 
Hello World 4 
Hello World 5 
Hello World 6 
Hello World 8 
Hello World 9 
Hello World 10 
Hello World 11 
Hello World 12 
Hello World 13 
Hello World 15 
Hello World 16 
Hello World 17 
Hello World 18 
Hello World 19
```

Note that `7` and `14` are missing because that's when the exception was thrown.